# How can I improve this R function

Tags: r

I am new to R. I created the function below to calculate the mean of dataset contained in 332 csv files. Seek advice on how I could improve this code. It takes 38 sec to run which make me think it is not very efficient.

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) {
        files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE) #creats list of files
        dat <- data.frame() #creates empty dataframe
                for(i in id){
                        dat<- rbind(dat,read.csv(files_list[i])) #combin all the monitor data together
}
        good <- complete.cases(dat) #remove all NA values from dataset
        mean(dat[good,pollutant]) #calculate mean
} #run time ~ 37sec - NEED TO OPTIMISE THE CODE
```

Comment: In short - never use loops in R, they are always slow. Also do you really need 332 files? this is horribly slow. Why not append them to one big file?

Comment: Maybe just create `dat` using `dat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(files_list, read.csv))` instead of the way you are doing it.

Comment: @lejlot, first - loops are not always slow, usually it depends on circumstances. 2- this is just some Coursera task.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I would love to see an example of fast loop in R :-)

Comment: @lejlot take a look [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html) there are some nice examples at the end too.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of creating a void `data.frame` and `rbind` each time with a `for loop`, you can store all `data.frames` in a list and combine them in one shot. You can also use `na.rm` option of mean function not to take into account `NA` values.

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332)
{
    files_list = list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)[id] 
    df         = do.call(rbind, lapply(files_list, read.csv))

    mean(df[[pollutant]], na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

Optional - I would increase the readability with `magrittr`:

```
library(magrittr)

pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332)
{
    list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)[id] %>%
        lapply(read.csv) %>%
        do.call(rbind,.) %>%
        extract2(pollutant) %>%
        mean(na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can improve it by using `data.table`'s `fread` function (see [Quickly reading very large tables as dataframes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r))
Also binding the result using `data.table::rbindlist` is way faster.

```
require(data.table)    

pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) {
    files_list = list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)[id]
    DT = rbindlist(lapply(files_list, fread))
    mean(DT[[pollutant]], na.rm=TRUE) 
}
```